# Can I uncompress .NET GZipStream using zlib?

Tags: gzip, zlib

Can I uncompress a bytestream that was compressed using the .NET GZipStream using the zlib library in C++?

Comment: It outputs standard .gz format.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to - use `gzopen` etc.

(The .NET `GZipStream` certainly *should* be writing "standard" gzip data, and zlib supports gzip, so...)